# Can I respond to my infinite loop by casting a creature spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I respond to my own triggered infinite loop with [Sporemound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSporemound%5d) and [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) by casting [Acidic Slime](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAcidic%20Slime%5d) to destroy [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) or by paying to activate [Gobbling Ooze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGobbling%20Ooze%5d) ability to destroy [Sporemound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSporemound%5d)?

Comment: Alternatively, you are entirely allowed to say you won't do anything to stop this, and if your opponent can't stop it either it's a draw. This might be a good idea if, for instance, you have low life total and your opponent has a flying creature you can't do anything about no matter how many saprolings you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may cast an instant spell to end the loop as you describe.

You may activate an ability to end the loop as you describe.

But you may not cast a creature spell (unless it has Flash).

---

The following is the loop in detail:

1. [You play a Forest or something]

   1. Sporemound's ability triggers.
2. You place Sporemound's ability on the stack.
3. Player's get priority.
4. Sporemound's ability resolves.

   1. You create a 1/1 green Saproling creature token that enters as a 1/1 green Forest Saproling land creature token.

      1. Sporemound's ability triggers.
5. Goto 2.

In step 3, you get to cast a spell or activate an ability in response to Sporemound's triggered ability. These will resolve before step 4 (because the last thing added to the stack resolves first). Step 4 will still happen (since the ability was added to the stack in step 2), but step 5 won't happen if Sporemound's ability doesn't trigger (e.g. because it's not there, or because the created Saproling didn't enter as a land), thus breaking the loop.

Note that the stack isn't empty in step 3, so the only spells you can cast are instant spells and spells with Flash, so casting [Acidic Slime](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAcidic%20Slime%5d) is out. Activated abilities of creatures are fine, though, so activating [Gobbling Ooze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGobbling%20Ooze%5d) is possible.

Comment: Oops, you can't cast Acidic Slime. See updated answer.